# JDBC mysql meta.getExportedKeys() returning empty resultset

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Hi I'm trying to get the foreig key for a given table, I'm using this code :

```
ResultSet rs = meta.getImportedKeys(_con.getCatalog(), null, _tableName);
        while (rs.next())
        {
            //get the foreignKeys
        }
ResultSet rs2 = meta.getExportedKeys(_con.getCatalog(), null, _tableName);
        while (rs2.next())
        {
            //get the foreignKeys
        }
```

The resultSet is empty, although the table contains a foreign key and is a foreign key to another table,

the `getImportedKeys` works fine.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Tables :

```
CREATE TABLE `COMMANDE` (
  `COMMANDE_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CLIENT_ID` int(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TOURNEE_ID` int(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`COMMANDE_ID`),
  KEY `CLIENT_ID` (`CLIENT_ID`),
  KEY `TOURNEE_ID` (`TOURNEE_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `commande_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CLIENT_ID`) REFERENCES `CLIENT` (`CLIENT_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `commande_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`TOURNEE_ID`) REFERENCES `TOURNEE` (`TOURNEE_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `CLIENT` (
  `CLIENT_ID` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `LIBELLE` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CLIENT_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I tried the code with both tables.

Comment: Could you show an example of the table definitions, including primary keys and foreign keys?

Comment: I edited my question, i tried it with both. Correct me if I'm wrong, but when running with table CLIENT, i should see that its a foreign key to COMMANDE in getExportedKeys() right ?

Comment: Have you checked your DDL statements? Do they execute on your system?

Comment: yes, my tables are created. and i can see the relatioships on sequel pro and mysql workbench.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is from the rather curious naming of the methods in JDBC, and the hard to grok description.

To get primary keys of a table, you should use [`getPrimaryKeys()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getPrimaryKeys%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), to get the foreign key of a table (and the primary key they reference), use [`getImportedKeys()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getImportedKeys%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

There are additional methods
 - [`getExportedKeys()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getExportedKeys%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) exposes the foreign keys that reference the specified table (so the table parameter specifies the table with the **primary key**)
 - [`getCrossReference()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getCrossReference%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is a combination of all of the above: you need to specify the tables on both sides of the constraint

Comment: Yes but  getExportedKeys() on table CLIENT should give me its foreign keys in table COMMANDE no? that's actually what I want, how can i do it?

Comment: Which driver are you using, I tried it with Connector/J 5.1.21 and it works as expected